# How to convert String to BigInteger representation and back in Java?

Tags: java, string, biginteger, type-conversion

Let's suppose I have a `String`, let's call it `foo`. This `String` can contain any value, like letters, numbers, special characters, `UTF-8` special characters, such as á and so on. For instance, this might be a real value:

```
"Érdekes szöveget írtam a tegnap, 84 ember olvasta."
```

I would like to have the following two methods:

```
public BigInteger toBigInteger(String foo)
{
    //Returns a BigInteger value that can be associated with foo
}

public String fromBigInteger(BigInteger bar)
{
    //Returns a String value that can be associated with bar
}
```

Then:

```
String foo = "Érdekes szöveget írtam a tegnap, 84 ember olvasta.";
System.out.println(fromBigInteger(toBigInteger(foo)));
//Output should be: "Érdekes szöveget írtam a tegnap, 84 ember olvasta."
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to use a `BigInteger` for that? It seems a very unnatural target data type.

Comment: I have an algorithm which encrypts and decrypts a big number, represented as a BigInteger. In fact the number to be encrypted or decrypted is in fact a textual message. So, on high-level I intend to use a String as input and get en encrypted version of that string. After that, on decryption I intend to use the encrypted message and decrypt it into another String. On low-level I am working with numbers, on high-level I am working with Strings

Comment: It would be much better to make your encryption code work with `byte[]` which is the normal approach. Converting various data types to arbitrary binary data is a common operation - converting them to BigInteger certainly isn't.

Comment: I am making operation with those numbers, so I should implement operations between byte arrays, such as their product, sum and so on. This would involve the implementation of a lot of methods. I am using BigInteger because all these operations are implemented.

Comment: Down-voter, can you enlighten me why do you consider my question un-helpful? What is wrong with my approach in your opinion? What should I do instead of my current idea?

Comment: I thought the point was to *encrypt* the data. (Coming up with your own encryption scheme is almost always a bad idea to start with, of course.) How you implement that is your business, but look at all other encryption APIs - it's no coincidence that they work on arbitrary binary data...

Comment: Well, thank you, @JonSkeet for sharing your ideas. I will think about implementing it with byte-array, involving methods for numbers in 256-base, but, for now I will stick to BigInteger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code will do what you expect:

```
public BigInteger toBigInteger(String foo)
{
    return new BigInteger(foo.getBytes());
}

public String fromBigInteger(BigInteger bar)
{
    return new String(bar.toByteArray());
}
```

However I don't understand why you would need to do this and I would be interested of your explanation.

Comment: This looks great, I hope it works. I will try that out and will let you know about the results. Thank you.

Comment: The encoding should be specified IMO - and this will break for any string starting with U+0000.

Comment: Probably he needed it for encryption purposes.

Comment: something similar could be done but instead of biginteger it is with integer?

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the "Why would you ever want to do that?"

```
String foo = "some text";
byte[] fooBytes = foo.getBytes();
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(fooBytes);
```

and then

```
foo = new String(bi.toByteArray());
```

**Edit from comments:** This is using the default charset. If the source `String` is not encoded via your default, you would want to specify the appropriate `Charset` to both `getBytes()` and the constructor for `String`. And if by chance you're using a charset that the first byte is zero, this will fail.

Comment: Should probably explicitly specify UTF-8 as charset when going from String -> byte[] -> String.  It may well not be the platform default.

Comment: Should *definitely* explicitly specify UTF-8. And this will fail if you end up with leading zeroes.

Comment: I thought about that, but honestly it should be using the default charset. What if the string *isn't* UTF-8? Re: leading zeroes ... what charset uses zero in the first byte? I don't know of one.

Comment: @BrianRoach: *Every* well-constructed Java string is representable in UTF-8. The same isn't true for all encodings. Also, if the OP needs to encrypt on one machine and decrypt in another, the encodings could differ. And U+0000 is a perfectly valid Unicode character.